# plupload Firefox uploads faster than the rest of the browsers

Tags: php, html, plupload

i just installed plupload on my server to test it out, it works a treat! love it, i was only wondering why does the upload goes much faster in firefox but not as fast in chrome, IE, safari?? this is on Windows 7 64Bit
my configurations are:

```
    runtimes: 'html5,silverlight,flash',
    browse_button: 'pickfiles',
    container: 'uploader',
    url: 'upload.php',
    chunk_size: '1mb',
    flash_swf_url : 'js/plupload.flash.swf',
    silverlight_xap_url : 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap',
```

it would be great if someone can give me an answer

Comment: Make a video.. show us what is going on. also.. which version of IE or safari.. also which runtimes are used...

Comment: Try to use less runtimes to see if they are causing this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, FF and Chrome are both the same speed, actually, chrome is a bit faster.  When I was doing the tests, I had both browsers running at the same time.  Not sure if this is correct or not, but when both ran at the same time, Firefox seems to have priority on the memory and runs the upload faster than chrome.

When I ran the test individually with a timer, Chrome actually performed better than Firefox, hope this helps.